# How can I add data to a Kotlin object and get it on a Vuejs page

Tags: vue.js, kotlin

I'm absolutely new to Kotlin. I'm trying to make a simple object on the backend side by **Kotlin** and get it on frontend **Vuejs**. How can I do something like this (this is the **raw code** of `HeaderBar.kt`, all my attempts were denied by compiler):

```
    object HeaderBar {

        val computed = object {
            fun items(): Array<Item> {
                items.add(Item(
                        "NY",
                        "Bill"
                ))
                return items
            }
        }

        data class Item(
                val city: String,
                val name: String
        )

    }
```

on Kotlin side?

And get the `items` on `HeaderBar.vue`. I'm not sure, but I do this by:

```
    <template>
        <div class="main-header">
            <div v-for="item in items" class="items">
                <span class="city">{{item.city}}</span>
                <span class="name">{{item.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    <template>

    <script>
        export default path.to.HeaderBar
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off all it's not simple question. Kotlin/Js not so mature as Kotlin/Jvm so there are many not so simple tasks.

First you need to somehow compile to javascript and then you need to attach `Vue` to kotlin/javascript code.

`Webpack` can make it easer, so I write a simple example to show you how to write your example in Kotlin.

**!Warning!: all code below is just draft (and has been writen only in demonstration purpose), so use it in your projects with special caution!**

Lets create project with below structure:
[image: project structure]

Application.kt:

```
package vue_test

fun VueJs(init: VueContext.() -> Unit) = Vue(VueContext().apply(init))

class VueContext {
    var el: String = ""
    var data: dynamic = js("{}")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val app: dynamic = VueJs {
        el = "#app"
        data = mapOf("items" to listOf(
                Item("NY", "Bill"),
                Item("Test", "Test2")
        )).toJs()
    }
}

data class Item(
        val city: String,
        val name: String
)

fun Map<String, Any>.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = object {}

    for ((key, value) in this) {
        when (value) {
            is String -> result[key] = value
            is List<*> -> result[key] = (value as List<Any>).toJs()
            else -> throw RuntimeException("value has invalid type")
        }
    }

    return result
}

fun List<Any>.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = js("[]")

    for (value in this) {
        when (value) {
            is String -> result.push(value)
            is Item -> {
                result.push(value.toJs())
            }
            else -> throw RuntimeException("value has invalid type")
        }
    }

    return result
}

fun Item.toJs(): dynamic {
    val result: dynamic = object {}

    result["city"] = this.city
    result["name"] = this.name

    return result
}
```

I have write few function `toJs` which converts Kotlin object to Js object. It theory you may use JSON serialization to simplify this, or other more simple solution (if exists).

Vue.kt

```
@file:JsModule("vue")
package vue_test

@JsName("default")
external open class Vue(init: dynamic)
```

In this file we have only Vue declarations.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test project</title>

</head>
<body class="testApp">
<h1>Kotlin-Js test</h1>

<div id="app">
    <div class="main-header">
        <div v-for="item in items" class="items">
            <span class="city">{{item.city}}</span>
            <span class="name">{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="frontend.bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Buldle has been created by webpack, and I has put this script to bottom because `Vue` needed to start his manipulations only then all necessary html tags has been already exists.

My build.gradle file with kotlin-frontend plugin and kotlin-js plugin:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.10'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-frontend-plugin:0.0.21"
    }
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-js'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.frontend'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlinFrontend {
    sourceMaps = true

    npm {
        dependency("vue")
    }

    webpackBundle {
        port = 8080
        bundleName = "frontend"
        contentPath = file('src/main/web')
        webpackConfigFile = project.projectDir.path + '/webpack.config.js'
    }
}

compileKotlin2Js {
    kotlinOptions.metaInfo = true
    kotlinOptions.outputFile = "$project.buildDir.path/js/${project.name}.js"
    kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
    kotlinOptions.moduleKind = 'commonjs'
    kotlinOptions.main = "call"
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-js:$kotlin_version"
}
```

settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'test-kotlin-vue'
```

and last file, custom webpack configuration:

```
var config = require('./build/WebPackHelper.js')
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    entry: config.moduleName,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./bundle'),
        publicPath: '/build/',
        filename: 'frontend.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: []
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve('js'), path.resolve('..', 'src'), path.resolve('.'), path.resolve('node_modules')],
        extensions: ['.js', '.css'],
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
        }
    },
    devtool: '#source-map'
};

console.log(module.exports.resolve.modules);
```

With `kotlin-frontend` plugin you could not use separate webpack config, but in this example `Vue` needed a full version to compile template, so it's needed to add alias in webpack. And I don't know how to do this in build.gradle.

Hope this will help you!

To start project with dev bundle run this command: `gradle build webpack-run`, and then open `http://localhost:8080` in your browser

To stop test run command: `gradle webpack-stop`